# Unable to create an admin user with chef-server?

Tags: centos, chef, chef-server

I want to configure chef-server over Centos 7, I installed the chef-server-core, then I added this line to /etc/hosts

```
192.168.0.4   chef.example.com
```

Then I put this command:

```
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Everything is ok, except when I tried to create a user with this command:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create admin admin admin admin@chef secret -f admin.pem
```

I got this message:

```
ERROR: Error connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/, retry 1/5
```

I made a lot of google and all solutions suggest to change the hostname in /etc/hosts, but not working in my machine.

Any Help!

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. And what you need to do is **rebooted your system and try again**. At least rebooting the system works for me.

Here is the explanation:

> Container needs to be **rebooted** after package is installed for things to work. Without rebooting, the error message the author mentioned would be received while trying to create a new user using `chef-server-ctl`

Here is the reference: [link](https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Chef_infrastructure_setup)